# How to I find the date with this format in string?

Tags: php, regex, datetime, web-scraping

So I have these strings:

```
 1. This is some 734 random 6272834 data 04 FEB 1:01 and maybe some here
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
 2. This is some random 1512 data 03 Jun 18:50
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 3. 23 APR 05:00 and maybe some here
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 4. 13 JUN 13:22
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I need to get that date and time.

I tried using explode, and then checking if an item is numeric, then next one has some alphabets and then 2 digits : 2 digits (you get the idea)

Is there a better way to extract that variable date (e.g. `13 JUN 13:22` or `23 APR 05:00`) from all those strings safely?

Maybe possible with regex?

Comment: Is your dates always in this format? 04 FEB 1:01 (2 digit day, 3 character month, single digit hour and 2 digit minutes) ?

Comment: Yes you are correct, look into using regex to pattern match the date.

Comment: @blupointmedia Yes, always that same format

Comment: How similar to a date as targeted can the random data get? Please show examples of things which look quite like a date, but should NOT match. Is there a ":" anywhere except in dates? Is there a list of special character sequences which identify a date but do not occur anywhere else (e.g. twelve months)? What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: @Yunnosch There is no ":" in the string except for dates

Comment: So anything which contains a ":" is guaranteed to be a date? Good, that makes it easy. Please show your code as a foundation for a solution, the one which you describe. Then explain how it failed. That is required, questions on StackOverflow are expected to demonstrate some own programming effort. Ohterwise we would have a lot of questions which describe needed programs and then wait for code solutions to be proposed. Questions without are considered too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a regex that will match the following...

```
[\d]{2} - matches exactly 2 digits
\s - matches single space
[\w]{3} - matches exactly 3 word characters
[\d]{1,2} - matches 1 or 2 digits, no more than 2, but at least 1
```

below is a working example...

```
$str = 'This is some 734 random 6272834 data 04 FEB 1:01 and maybe some here';

preg_match('#[\d]{2}\s[\w]{3}\s[\d]{1,2}:[\d]{2}#', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Please explain your solution, that helps to fight the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a source for unpaid programming work.

Comment: If you are unsure what the exact question/gloas is (which I can understand with this question), then pleas use your commenting privilege to ask for clarification. Or in the presence of other clarification questions in existing comments wait for them to be answered. If you are not unsure then please avoid the "Try this" impression, which makes an answer come of less assertive.

Comment: @Yunnosch I can't write regex, but I can understand it, this was perfectly helpful, I'll try to practice more with Regex, thank you guys.

Comment: J. Doe, please accept the answer if it worked for you. I explained what each section of the regex is doing per @Yunnosch request.

Comment: @Yunnosch is that a better explanation? : )

Comment: J.Doe, yes, that you cannot write regex is what I surmised. Not knowing how to program yourself and then asking for a solution here is what I was talking about. That is not what StackOverflow is meant for. Answeres like this support that misunderstanding. You will find many people who happily help you with a problem which you encounter while programming. Things you need but did not try to program yourself is what some people will jump to give you for free, but against the idea of StackOverflow.

Comment: bluepointmdia Any explanation is better than none. I am not so sure about your understanding of what `[]`, mean, but it works and the explanation is not wrong. The interesting part, which makes sure that nothing but a date matches, that would be the most helpful part of the explanation...